# How can I extract a list of lists into single data frame (ideally by name references)?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists:

```
> dput(results)
list(list(type = "sales", value = 9L, all_time_value = 833L), 
    list(type = "gmv", value = 3644.21716861478, all_time_value = 344375.321075978), 
    list(type = "aov", value = 404.913018734976, all_time_value = 413.415751591811), 
    list(type = "acr", value = 0.108433734939759, all_time_value = 0.149283154121864), 
    list(type = "initiated-chats", value = 89L, all_time_value = 10299L), 
    list(type = "chats-claimed", value = 82L, all_time_value = 5497L), 
    list(type = "chats-per-available-user", value = 3.15384615384615, 
        all_time_value = 57.2604166666667), list(type = "rating", 
        value = 5L, all_time_value = 4.58640776699029))
```

Which is structured like this:

```
> library(dplyr)
> results %>% str
List of 8
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "sales"
  ..$ value         : int 9
  ..$ all_time_value: int 833
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "gmv"
  ..$ value         : num 3644
  ..$ all_time_value: num 344375
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "aov"
  ..$ value         : num 405
  ..$ all_time_value: num 413
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "acr"
  ..$ value         : num 0.108
  ..$ all_time_value: num 0.149
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "initiated-chats"
  ..$ value         : int 89
  ..$ all_time_value: int 10299
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "chats-claimed"
  ..$ value         : int 82
  ..$ all_time_value: int 5497
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "chats-per-available-user"
  ..$ value         : num 3.15
  ..$ all_time_value: num 57.3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ type          : chr "rating"
  ..$ value         : int 5
  ..$ all_time_value: num 4.59
```

**This list is extracted from a backend system and will always contain the same metrics, but those values may not always come in in this specific order.**

I want to extract the elements of each list into a single data frame consisting of three rows (`type`, `value`, `all_time_value`) and eight columns, with each column named according to the corresponding value in `$ type`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbindlist` could be more efficient, try out `data.frame(t(data.table::rbindlist(results)))`.

```
# or with the columns name
df <- data.frame(t(data.table::rbindlist(results)))
df <- setNames(df[-1, ], sapply(df[1, ], as.character))

# output
                      sales          gmv          aov          acr initiated-chats chats-claimed chats-per-available-user       rating
value             9.0000000 3644.2171686  404.9130187    0.1084337      89.0000000    82.0000000                3.1538462    5.0000000
all_time_value 8.330000e+02 3.443753e+05 4.134158e+02 1.492832e-01    1.029900e+04  5.497000e+03  

       5.726042e+01 4.586408e+00
```

Comment: This produces a similar result; please explain how this approach could be more efficient.  Also, the difference for me using this method over the one proffered by 
JohnCoene is that the columns aren't named using `$ type`; instead, the values in `$ type` are listed as elements in the first row and the columns are given system default names (`X1`, `X2`, etc.). As such, I will have to rename the columns according to the first row, then remove the first row.  Or is there a quick way - perhaps an optional argument - that I can call to use the `$ type` values as the column names?

Comment: For `rbindlist` efficiency, read [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/rbindlist). I edited my answer to include column names. Please note that if `type` represents the column names, it's no more relevant as a row. So you have to choose between three rows (including `type`) and two rows with `type` as `colnames`.

Comment: I have compared both solutions (yours and JohnCoene's) and even though JohnCoene's is more concise, your solution provides a more usable and robust data frame.  Therefore, I am changing the selected answer because even though both provide a solution, this is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

First flatten the whole thing into a `data.frame`.

```
df <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(results, as.data.frame))
```

then flip it around

```
t(df)
```

---

All-in-one approach:

```
df <- t(do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(results, as.data.frame)))
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.  I have simplified it to this: `df <- t(do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(results, as.data.frame)))`